# c# LDAP membership enumeration

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

here is my problem: I need to enumerate the members of certain groups in our Active Directory. The complication is that the DN of the objects that are in the 'membersOf' property of the groups do not contain the identifier I need. Specifically, the `CN` of the user object is useless to me, only a property of the user object (the `userID`) is useful.

So three approaches comes to mind:

1. I can first enumerate the group to get a list of `DN`'s in the group, and then do a lookup on each user DN to find out their `userID`
2. I can enumerate every user in the AD, grabbing their `userID` & their `membersOf` collection, and then check afterwards if they have the right memberships.
3. I could grab a list of all users with their `CN`'s and `userID`'s, and then enumerate the groups to get the member CN's. Then I could join the lists on the original list to get my list of member `userID`'s.

Some problems immediately appear - option 1) will generate an extremely large number of subqueries and congest network traffic (undesirable), and option 2) pulls a HUGE amount of data from AD (something like 30mb). Option 3) is middle of the road - but it still pulls quite a bit of data and has multiple queries. Is there another option for how to do this which does not have these problems?

I am doing this in c# using the `System.DirectoryServices` tools.

Thank you in advance for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there's an option #4, too:

- you could set up a `DirectorySearcher` which enumerates users
- you could define `memberOf=.......` as one of your search criteria
- you can define what attributes you need from the directory searcher very easily

If this works (and I'm under the impression I got this to work before - but it's been quite a while!) then you could do one, single fairly focused search and automatically get your information that you need.

Try something like this:

```
// define the "root" of your search (where to begin)
DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://cn=users,dc=yourcompany,dc=com");

DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);

// set properties
searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

// define search filter
searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Person)(memberof=CN=YourGroup,OU=Users,DC=YourDomain,DC=com))";

// define attributes to load
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userid"); 
... add more if needed .....

foreach(SearchResult entry in searcher.FindAll())
{
   string userid = entry.Properties["userid"][0].ToString();
}
```